# Jenkins “xcodebuild: error : not contain an Xcode project or workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

Developing an iOS Mobile application, while building with `jenkins`,throws an error:

> “xcodebuild: error: The directory
>   /Users/hemant/.jenkins/workspace/SmokeProject_iOS does not contain an
>   Xcode project or workspace.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution.

Just find path in finder and replace code in `SmokeProject_iOS` folder and its working for me.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue and this didn't solve it (as I was having a settings issue with my Jenkins GitHub plugin), but it did give me insight as to how the Jenkins server stores the data on the server, which makes debugging much easier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to move to **Advanced Xcode build options** and fill in **Xcode Project Directory** relative path to your directory with *.xcodeproj file
In my case it was /Users/nik/jenkins/workspace/myIOSProject/Builds/iOS/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj, but jenkins looked in /Users/nik/jenkins/workspace/myIOSProject/